# serial communictation between python and arduino

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I send values arduino to python. This is part of my code.

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Timer.h"



int IR_sensor = A0;
int value;

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(IR_sensor, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  long IR_value = analogRead(IR_sensor);
  long IR_range = gp2y0a21yk(IR_value);

  //Serial.println(IR_value);
  //Serial.print(IR_range);
  //Serial.println("cm");
  //Serial.println();
  if (IR_range < 50)
  {
    value = 1;
    Serial.println(value);
  }

  else {
    value = 0;
    Serial.println(value);
  }
  delay(1000);

      if (value == 1)
      {
        Serial.println("1234"); 

      }

    }

long gp2y0a21yk(long IR_value)
{
  if (IR_value < 10)
  {
    IR_value = 10;
  }

  return ((67870.0 / (IR_value - 3.0)) - 40.0) / 10;
}
```

SO THIS CODE has two options. First value =0 or value = 1 and then 1234

This is my python code

```
import serial
import time
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime
import cv2
import boto3


port ="COM15"
brate = 9600
arduino =serial.Serial(port, baudrate = brate, timeout=None)


while True:

    data= arduino.readline()str = data[:-2].decode()
    print(str)


    if str=="0":
        print("nobody")
```

What I wonder is this part. data=arduino.readline() this code reads the value 0 or 1 and 1234. WHAT I want to do is saving this value to data1 and data2 and I want to use this value! For example, if python gets value=0 I want to save this value to a so a=0 and then use if clause and if python gets value =1 and 1234 I want to save this a=1 and b=1234 and use it to if clause. Do you have any ideas? I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your arduino will output only either 0 or 1 and 1234, just add `else` after your `if` statement.

```
a = int(str)
if str=="0":
    print("nobody")
else:
    b = int(arduino.readline()[:-2].decode())
```

Comment: 1234 can be changed according to people's id card. But I will try it and let you know I really appreciate it.... you are my hero

Comment: I see. The if-else will work regardless of id numbers because it's the first line that is being checked (which will either be 0 or 1).

Comment: What I want to do is lie this. if value =0 no body and if value =1, it goes two ways 1. value ->1 check id(1234) -> no id -> take photo  2.value -> 1 check id(1234)-> id exist  finish it.

Comment: In that case, write another if-else statement within the else body, so that it checks whether id exists only after when 1 is received.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.